# Symfony : easy way to format FORMS with CSS?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

We're building a web site with Symfony 2. We  generate a unique URL and send it by email to user who forgot their password, so they can reset their password.

We're building a simple form to reset a password. We have two labels ('Enter your new password' and 'Enter your new password again') with a textbox beside each.

We wanted the textbox to align with each other.

Lazy solution was to figure out two strings of the same length (!)

But I would have wanted to format them with CSS or put them in a table ...

Is that possible at all with Symfony's form ?  I read documentation about customizing templates, but when we tried the solution proposed by Symfony's docs the widgets (textboxes) were not rendering ...

Here are some pics of the issue :

[Crooked textboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fX9Aw.png)

[Lazy solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFqX2.png)

Here is the code of the twig where I think(!) the formatting should be done

```
{% block blockPrincipal_mp %}
<h1>{{ titre }}</h1>
{{ form_start(form) }}


<div class="containerForm">
    <div class="error">
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
    </div>
    {{ form_rest(form) }}





    {{ form_end(form) }}
    {% for flashMessage in app.session.flashbag.get('success') %}
        <div class="confirm"><p>    {{ flashMessage }}</p></div>
    {% endfor %}
        </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Do you have custom controller code or are you using FOSUserBundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render all the different elements of the forms individually as opposed to just rendering it all at one time with `form_rest(form)` as you have in your example. `form_rest()` is going to render whatever hasn't been rendered yet.  And up to this point, All that's been rendered are the errors.

I don't know what your form property's names are but here's an example:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}

    <div class="form_errors">{{ form_errors(form) }}</div>

    {# output all pieces of the username element individually #}
    <div class="form_label">{{ form_label(form.username) }}</div>
    <div class="form_input">{{ form_widget(form.username) }}</div>
    <div class="form_errors">{{ form_errors(form.username) }}</div>

    {# output all pieces of the password element individually #}
    <div class="form_label">{{ form_label(form.password) }}</div>
    <div class="form_input">{{ form_widget(form.password) }}</div>
    <div class="form_errors">{{ form_errors(form.password) }}</div>

    {{ form_rest(form) }}

{{ form_end(form) }}
```

This way you can control what HTML wrappers surround each piece of your form elements.

Note that you can also output the username and password fields by doing...

```
{{ form_row(form.username) }} {{ form_row(form.password) }}
```

...and it will still output the label, widget and errors but will use the default layout for those form types that is defined in your twig templates. So you have more control of rendering the parts if you do them individually.

This is great for custom forms and custom templates, however you can also override the default form element's layout if you want more control over how individual form elements are rendered throughout your site, by extending the form fields template.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html

Comment: But now there's a red asterisk (*) at the end of each label (between label and textbox). Can't seem to make them go away ... :(

Comment: That's probably because your default input field template uses a red asterisk for required fields.  If you want to override how required fields are displayed globally you can create your `fields.html.twig` template override in accordance to the symfony guide I linked to and alter how it's displayed.  Or if you need to make it unrequired, set `'required'=>false` in your form builder for those fields.

Answer (score 1):

The `RepeatedType` field can be dispayed separately:

```
{{ form_row(form.password.first) }}
{{ form_row(form.password.second) }}
```

or more controlled:

```
{{ form_label(form.password.first) }}
{{ form_widget(form.password.first) }}

{{ form_label(form.password.second) }}
{{ form_widget(form.password.second) }}
```